# a href link of an image not taking up full image size

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, href

I have set up 3 mini-features on an index page but for whatever reason the links only show up on the top 20% of the image on the desktop version. When on mobile the linkable area is perfectly fine.  The site's core is running off Bootstrap.

```
  <a href="courses.php" class="col-sm-4 fade-in two">
    <img src="images/Mini-Features/Book-Your-Private-Lesson.jpg" 
      alt="Start your private lessons, Book a class today with Universal Ballroom" 
      title="Start your private lessons, Book a class today with Universal Ballroom" class="img-responsive"> 
  </a>   

  <a href="courses.php" class="col-sm-4 fade-in two">
    <img src="images/Mini-Features/Upcoming-Studio-Party.jpg" 
      alt="Upcoming Event: April 14th, Studio Party at Universal Ballroom in Argyle Illinois"
      title="Upcoming Event: April 14th, Studio Parth at Universal Ballroom in Argyle Illinois" class="img-responsive">   
  </a>

  <a href="courses.php" class="col-sm-4 fade-in two">
    <img src="images/Mini-Features/New-Class-Schedule.jpg"
      alt="Get the April Class Schedule, Click here."
      title="Get the April Class Schedule, Click here." class="img-responsive">     
  </a>
```

Here is a link to the current development version of the site:

http://sandbox.graphics/Development/universal-ballroom/index.php

Comment: Don't link to a "current development version" of your site - that's likely to change, so the link won't stay useful. If you want to share a demo, you should use something like jsFiddle, or the built-in Stack Snippets.

Answer (score 2):

If you inspect the image with Developer Tools you recognize that another Element (`div.row`) is in Front of your Image.

By applying a high `z-index`-value you can place the image in front of the other element (`div.row`), and the link will work on the whole image

**CSS**

```
a.col-sm-4.fade-in.two {
      z-index: 10000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
<div style="margin:20px 0px;">
```

to

```
<div class="row" style="margin:20px 0px;">
```

Chrome's dev tools are a great resource to see what's actually going on here. Another simple fix may be to simply apply a z-index to the funky a element.

Comment: Amazing. *smacks head* Thanks!

Comment: No problem! The only reason I spotted it so quick is because i've been frustrated by this same issue in the past. Glad to help :)